# MULTIPLE FILE INPUTS IN map function of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Actually i want to implement an algorithm for data clustering in mongodb.
I have two files.

1. Data file : It has data points with time stamps.

Ex:

```
Time stamp | data
6| 46, 36, A    [46,26,A is a data with three dimensions and 6 is  time stamp  at which data came]
7|90,45,B
8|45,12,C
9|34,67,D
```

1. Config file(meta data)

Dimension  category  granularity

```
0, N, 4,0,100  [ 0 th dimesion is numeric has granularity 4 and starts from 0 & goes till 100 i.e. 0-25, 26-50, 51-75,76-100]
1,N,2,0,50      [Ist dimension has gran = 2 thus 0-25, 26-50]
2,C,A,B,C,D [2nd dimension is categorical and as values a,b,c,d therefore granularity 4]
```

Now i have to build a MAP-REDUCE function in mongodb that give me d signature of data that came at time stamps by tking input from the above mentioned files:

```
6- 1,1,0 
7- 3,1,1
```

nd so on....

I have to run map reduce taking both files as input.. but i couldnt find any method to take input mutiple files in mongodb map-reduce.
can anybody pls guide how to go about it if any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The input for a mapReduce job is a MongoDB collection and can not be a data file.

But, in your case, you won't need mapReduce(), as there is no "reduce" part - all you do is transforming 1:1 the input records into output records.

So, the first step is to store the data file into a collection "inp" - storing the time series as an array in a document. If your data file should result in a document bigger than 16MB, you'll have to split it up into several documents - for the sake of the example I will store only 2 timestamp elements per document. I did the example in JavaScript for mongo shell:

```
PATH = "/home/ronald/mongotest/";
DATA = "data.file";
ELEMS_PER_DOC = 2; // number of emelements in "series" per document

db.data.drop();
data = cat( PATH + DATA );
lines = data.split("\n")
lines = lines.splice(0,lines.length-1);
series = [];
lines.forEach(function( line ) {
    if ( series.length >= ELEMS_PER_DOC ) {
        db.data.insert({ "series": series });
        series = [];
    }
    l = line.split("|");
    timestamp = l[0];
    d = l[1].split(",");
    series.push( { "ts": timestamp, "data": d } );
});
db.data.insert({ "series": series });
```

For the given data file:

```
6|46,36,A
7|90,45,B
8|45,12,C
9|34,67,D
```

This results in the following collection:

```
> db.data.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515e735657a0887a97cc8d23"),
    "series" : [
        {
            "ts" : "6",
            "data" : [
                "46",
                "36",
                "A"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ts" : "7",
            "data" : [
                "90",
                "45",
                "B"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515e735657a0887a97cc8d24"),
    "series" : [
        {
            "ts" : "8",
            "data" : [
                "45",
                "12",
                "C"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ts" : "9",
            "data" : [
                "34",
                "67",
                "D"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[ Note: If you don't want to store your input data in MongoDB, then just build up the "series" array and use this as input in the third step. Watch the memory usage on your client machine! ]

The next step is to generate, from the config file, the JavaScript functions, that will be used to transform the data according to the rule set. Actually, this will be an array of functions, to avoid a hard-coded limit to three dimensions.

```
PATH = "/home/ronald/mongotest/";
CONFIG = "config.file";

config = cat( PATH + CONFIG );
lines = config.split("\n")
lines = lines.splice(0,lines.length-1);
// array of functions - index = dimension
funcs = [];
lines.forEach(function( line ) {
    x = line.split(",");
    f = "";
    if ( x[1] == "N" ) {
        // Numeric rule: 
        // x[2] = granularity
        // x[3],x[4] lower,upper range
        // the function to be called for the given value looks like:
        //    function( val ) returns: the interval or "n/a" if outside range
        // the interval is given by (val - (val modulo intervalSize)) / intervalSize
        // the intervalSize is (max - min) / granularity
        intervalSize = (x[4] - x[3]) / x[2];
        f = "function (val) {";
        f += "  if ( val < "+x[3]+" || val > "+x[4]+" ) return 'n/a';";
        f += "  return (val - val % "+intervalSize+") / "+intervalSize+";";
        f += "}";
    } else if ( x[1] == "C" ) {
        // Categoric rule: 
        // return the position of value in the array of params
        // skip dimension and rule type
        x = x.splice(2, x.length-1);
        // build parameter array
        pa = '[';
        x.forEach( function(p) { pa += '"' + p + '",' } );
        pa += ']';
        // the function will return -1 if value not found in array
        f = "function (val) { return "+pa+".indexOf(val) }";
    }
    else {
        // unknown rule type
        f = "function (val) { return 'rule err' }";
    }
    eval( "fx = "+f );
    funcs.push( fx );
});
```

For the given config file:

```
0,N,4,0,100
1,N,2,0,50
2,C,A,B,C,D
```

this generates the following function array:

```
> funcs
[
    function (val) {  if ( val < 0 || val > 100 ) return 'n/a';  return (val - val % 25) / 25;},
    function (val) {  if ( val < 0 || val > 50 ) return 'n/a';  return (val - val % 25) / 25;},
    function (val) { return ["A","B","C","D",].indexOf(val) }
]
```

Now, the third and final part: create the output collection from the input collection:

```
db.out.drop();
cursor = db.data.find();
cursor.forEach( function (doc) {
    doc.series.forEach( function (serie) {
        for ( i=0; i<serie.data.length; i++ ) {
            // apply transformation function for each dimension
            serie.data[i] = funcs[i]( serie.data[i] );            
        }
    });
    db.out.insert( doc );
})
```

And the final result is:

```
> db.out.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515e974c57a0887a97cc8d2f"),
    "series" : [
        {
            "ts" : "6",
            "data" : [
                1,
                1,
                0
            ]
        },
        {
            "ts" : "7",
            "data" : [
                3,
                1,
                1
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515e974c57a0887a97cc8d30"),
    "series" : [
        {
            "ts" : "8",
            "data" : [
                1,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "ts" : "9",
            "data" : [
                1,
                "n/a",
                3
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```